# Django project couldn't find image given absolute path:

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have the following line in an html file of my Django project:

```
'<img src="/Users/edamame/workspace/git/my-analysis/django_services/mysite/polls/my_img.jpg" >'
```

However, when the page is loaded, the image can't be found and below is the error message in the console:

```
[22/Aug/2018 20:04:51] "POST /polls/polls/search HTTP/1.1" 200 733
Not Found: /Users/edamame/workspace/git/my-analysis/django_services/mysite/polls/my_img.jpg
[22/Aug/2018 20:04:51] "GET /Users/edamame/workspace/git/my-data-analysis/django_services/mysite/polls/my_img.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2315
```

Any idea why the image can't be found? Thanks!

Comment: Where is nginx/apache configuration and {% static %} tag?!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to put the source at the very beginning. Depends where your file is located. If it's a folder before use dots at the beginning of the path.

Comment: Please 2-3 lines answer in comments